# How to replace part of a string in between common features of the string by using Python27

Tags: python, replace

I am working on a Python script to interactively replace pin numbers (part of the string) in between common features within a set of web service links (imagine as the entire string). See below as a case:

The entire string:

`http://www.adamscountyarcserver.com/adamscountyarcserver/rest/services/Adams_County_Basemap_Complete/MapServer/14/query?where=**PIN%3D%27010059400200%27**&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4326&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson`

The part of the string I want to replace/pin number:
`010059400200`

The common features that are surrounded in the start and in the end of the pin number:
`PIN%3D%27` and `%27`

I tried python built-in functions such as `replace` `substitute` and `partition`, but it seemed like all of them required me to specific the word itself that is to be replaced rather than specifying the relative location of the word within the entire string.

Any solutions or ideas?

Comment: Python strings are immutable, so it is **impossible** to replace a part of a string. The only thing you can do is take one or more parts of a string and then combine (some of) those parts  with other stuff into a new string.

Comment: I meant whatever strategy. Even including creating another new string variable.

Comment: Then please update your title, it now reads 'replace part of a string'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but I think `re.sub` might be the easiest:

```
>>> import re
>>> newpin = '1234567890'
>>> re.sub(r'PIN%3D%27\d+%27', 'PIN%3D%27' + newpin + '%27', text)
'http://www.adamscountyarcserver.com/adamscountyarcserver/rest/services/Adams_County_Basemap_Complete/MapServer/14/query?where=PIN%3D%271234567890%27&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=4326&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson'
```